# What is the nationality of Bayonetta's protagonist?

Tags: bayonetta

The game Bayonetta has a strong European influence. But about the main character...

What is her nationality?

She appears Italian to me judging by her design.

Comment: I do know she was apparently born in the 15th century, so given the rest of her backstory she's certainly European.  I'd expect she is probably Italian, actually.  I don't think geographic specifics are ever given, though.

Comment: From the FAQ: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*  What problem will this help you solve?

Comment: @Steve V. We have plenty of lore questions, why would this one be any different? It seems to me that this question is _hard to answer_ (probably requiring digging up some old interview, if the info exists at all), but offtopic - certainly not. Why all the downvotes, I have no clue.

Comment: Yeah, I think there's not really an answer to this question, but we have lots of other lore questions (and meta discussion has decided that they're allowed).

Comment: @SteveV. I also can quote the FAQ, "If your question generally covers things such as … Plot and characters in games"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bayonetta/Cereza is born in Vigrid, a fictional city state in Europe.

Biographical Information
Name     Cereza
Gender   Female
Born     December 19, 1411 Vigrid
Clan    Umbra Witches
Family  Balder - Father,  Rosa - Mother

Source: [Bayonetta Wiki](http://bayonetta.wikia.com/wiki/Cereza)

Comment: Got a source to back it up?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's right there on the wiki, cba putting a link up, google is your friend.

Comment: Kindly put a link in your answer then. Answers are expected to be stand-alone and not require every single person who reads it to do follow-up research—that's the job of the user writing the answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The answer IS stand-alone. The only reason for a link is so people can check if the answer is really true, something they can do on their own very well. I will put it in since you asked so nicely, but it's really not relevant.

Comment: We do things a bit differently around here than most places. Thank you! This will gather more upvotes, since it's easier to judge now, and those votes beside it will help future readers gauge at a glance our confidence in this answer. Cites make only a small difference, but it adds up!